# Can't deploy app engine project XML error validating appengine-web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

When i try to deploy a project to google app engine i get the error

An internal error occurred during: "Deploying TestService to Google".
XML error validating D:\Workspace\TestService\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml against D:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4\docs\appengine-web.xsd

It seems like the file appengine-web.xsd is missing. inside the folder
D:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4 there's only a libs subfolder.

I've just done an update in eclipse and it was working before that. Why is this file missing, is it required and where can i find it?